# Submit an input box OR a select box (not both)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I want to have the option for my users to submit a form that they have the option to either use either the select box or the input text box, but not both. Here is my form code:

```
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div id="incident-type" class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Incident Type (Use this box or the common incident box)</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input id="textinput" name="incident_type" type="text" class=" form-control">
      </div>

    </div>  

<!-- Select Box -->
           <div id="incident-control-box" class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Common Incidents (Use this box or the incident type box)</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <select onclick="hideInputBox()" id="textinput incident-type1" name="incident_type" type="text" class=" form-control" >
            <option value="blank"></option>
      <option value="AFA Commercial">AFA Commercial</option>
      <option value="AFA Residential">AFA Residential</option>
      <option value="MVA W/Injuries">MVA W/Injuries</option>
      <option value="Gas Leak Outside">Gas Leak Outside</option>
      <option value="Gas Leak Inside">Gas Leak Inside</option>
      <option value="Investigation">Investigation</option>
      <option value="Possible Structure Fire">Possible Structure Fire</option>

          </select>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Then here is my code from my PHP where it gets the input boxes of the form:

```
  $incident_type     = $row['incident_type'];
```

The problem I run into is that I want either one of them to submit depending on what the user chooses to fill out. Currently only the select input works, not the text box input also.

**UPDATE:** See my answer I added below, I have figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out eventually by using jQuery. I had used some help from user bob-the-destroyer who commented and told me some step how I should implement this solution. I basically had a hidden input and copied over the text or selected value from the two inputs on the form and had it submitted in the hidden input. I transferred over the text/value of what was entered by using the jQuery code below.

HTML:

```
<!-- Text input-->
<div id="incident-type" class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Incident Type (Use this box or the common incident box)</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="input-incident1" name="input-incident1" type="text" class=" form-control">
  </div>

</div>  



        <!-- Select Box -->

       <div id="incident-control-box" class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Common Incidents (Use this box or the incident type box)</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select id="input-incident2" name="input-incident2" type="text" class=" form-control" >
        <option value=""></option>
  <option value="AFA Commercial">AFA Commercial</option>
  <option value="AFA Residential">AFA Residential</option>
  <option value="MVA W/Injuries">MVA W/Injuries</option>
  <option value="Gas Leak Outside">Gas Leak Outside</option>
  <option value="Gas Leak Inside">Gas Leak Inside</option>
  <option value="Investigation">Investigation</option>
  <option value="Possible Structure Fire">Possible Structure Fire</option>

      </select>
  </div>

</div>  

<input type="hidden" id="incident_type" name="incident_type">
```

jQuery:

```
 <script>
          $(function () {
    var $src = $('#input-incident1'),
        $dst = $('#incident_type');
    $src.on('input', function () {
        $dst.val($src.val());
    });
        });

        </script>

                <script>
                $(function () {
    var $src = $('#input-incident2'),
        $dst = $('#incident_type');
    $src.on('input', function () {
        $dst.val($src.val());
    });
    });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to do this the way you're trying to because the `incident_type` parameters collide. When that happens, servers pick one arbitrarily - most I've seen take the last one in the parameter list. You're going to want to give the inputs different names, but then you have lots of options:

- Use the text box if it's not empty, since it's more custom.
- Use the text box if the select is blank.
- Force a `select` selection and provide an `Other` option. Use the text box if `Other` was selected.
- Make the user explicitly pick which to use with some toggle (that can hide the input not being used, if you like). Submit the toggle's value too, and use the field it specifies.

If you really want to keep logic out of the server, you could write some JavaScript that toggles the `name` attribute from one input to the other. That way, only one will be sent over, but this feels sort of gross to me.

Comment: Thank you for the information! That's what I figured, so I'm working on this with PHP to see if I can make this work. I'll let you know if I need help still.

Comment: For the client-side javascript way, instead of tampering with element names, maybe have a _hidden_ "incident_type" named input and don't bother naming either of the _shown_ input and select fields. Then for both the shown input and select elements, add a "change" event listener that copies the value of whichever field the client is currently interacting with to this hidden input.  But yes, many ways to do this.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer, can you explain further or give me a piece of code for the event listener for the "change" event? Would I need to use jQuery? I know some JavaScript, but not jQuery.

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you! See my answer below that I added.